Building an algorithm to use Bayes conditional probability in conjunction with association rules to build predictive models?
Association rules are a data mining technique used to identify interesting relationships between variables in large datasets. These rules take the form "if-then" statements, where the presence of certain items imply the presence of others. Common measures used to evaluate these associations include support, confidence and lift. Association rules are primarily descriptive rather than predictive. They describe relationships and patterns found in the data. And while lift, for example, provides an indication of the likelihood of association between items, it's more about association strength within the dataset than predictive capability for individual instances.
Bayesian probability is a statistical concept that represents the degree of belief or confidence in the occurrence of an event, incorporating both prior knowledge and observed evidence.
Would it be possible to use bayesian probability in conjunction with association rules to build a predictive model?
We could use association rules to identify patterns, and calculate the prior probabilities based on these association rules. As new data becomes available, update the prior probabilities using Bayesian inference. These updated posterior probabilities from Bayesian inference can be used to predict future events. Continuously evaluate the performance of the model using new data and refine it as needed.
This will be particularly useful in high dimensional data where other modeling techniques may suffer.
Is this interesting to build? How can we transform association rules metrics into prior probabilities?
